# the page frame is corrupting

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I would like to create a frame around the website. It would overlap elements.

[target look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQdhg.png)

I created a div, which I stylized, but the frame is bug and looks like this

[actual look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk2U4.png)

This is my React  code

```
class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="frame">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="grid">
            <div className="grid-item grid-item-1">{<Toggle />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item grid-item-2">{<Text />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item experience">{<StatsExp />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item clients">{<StatsClients />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item articles">{<StatsArticles />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item words">{<StatsWordsCV />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item grid-item-3">
              {<Picture />}
              {<Social />}
            </div>
            <div className="grid-item grid-item-5">{<Navigation />}</div>
            <div className="grid-item grid-item-6">{<Butt />}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

This is my css code

```
**.frame {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 68vh;
  border-left: 1px green solid;
  border-right: 1px green solid;
  border-top: 1px green solid;
  border-bottom: 1px green solid;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
}**

.container {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`.frame` has a fixed `height`:

```
height: 68vh;
```

Just remove this line from your `.frame` css

Comment: now the frame is around the page, as I use padding exp. 120px to move it in, nothing happens